# ssh based authentication in expressjs

Tags: node.js, express, ssh

I am currently using expressjs with node.js as my rest server for my website. Currently users can login on to my website and start some actions through ui. They want to automate this stuff and I am looking for ways to achieve that. Some of the ways I can think is:

1. Create a new request which can take login creds as part of reuest parameters and execute the desired the actions. My users would have to save their password as pain text for automations which doesn't seem OK to me.
2. login using ssh similar to how bitbucket/github takes our public ssh key and lets up do codepush with out writing the password everytime. How do I implement this kind of setup. My users want to execute everytime they deploy in  test machine. So they will put my script in server restart script.

If I have to adda new ssh based authentication, are there any npm modules which can help me with implementation?

I am using [mean.io](https://github.com/linnovate/mean) boiler plate code and login is currently is based on default login protocol of theirs, where in I save the hashed password and compare that during login.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think dealing with public-private key pairs is probably more trouble than it is worth.  Perhaps you can go with a third option:

Allow users to generate API keys from your web interface. The keys will be "long" randomly generated strings (GitHub uses a 40 character long hexadecimal string for its keys). They can be used for making API requests in place of a password in a username-password pair. For additional security, allow users to limit a key's usage to a certain IP (range).

Also, make sure your application is being served over HTTPS if it is not already.

Example flow:

1. User **tim** generates a random API key on your site (`aisjd8auasdjsd80j43j`).
2. **tim** wants to make a request to your API. In the request, **tim** sets an authorization header:

   ```
   GET /api/v1/list-all HTTP/1.1
   Host: example.com
   X-API-Auth: tim:aisjd8auasdjsd80j43j
   ...
   ```
3. Your API verifies the `X-API-Auth` header, checking if **tim** owns the given API key.
4. Your API returns the requested information on sucess.

Also, it may be worth using using [HTTP basic authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_basic_authentication) instead of the custom `X-API-Auth` header, as I did in the above example. I believe it would be slightly easier in command line tools like curl to make HTTP basic authentication requests, rather than setting a custom header.